# I keep getting a yellow light on a GFCI

Tags: electrical

Old GFCI died.....installed a new 20 amp one.  Have wired it everyway possible and I still get an orange light.

No power to the appliance.   Is it possible the outlet is bad?

Comment: GFCI lights can mean anything. There is no standard for that. You need to read the instructions *anyway* because that's a Code requirement (NEC 110.3(B)), so see if it mentions anything.  Also, how do you define "died"?  If you mean "started tripping and won't reset", then my next question is: was anything plugged into it and are any wires attached to the LOAD terminals on the back?

Comment: Have you by chance reversed the wires to the LINE and LOAD terminals?

Comment: **sigh** "wired it every way possible"???!!!  The wiring of a GFCI outlet is very straightforward,  Power in goes to the line, power to the downstream outlets go on the load terminals.   To diagnose, disconnect the load wires and try to see if it will reset  then.  If it will, you have a problem with shorts or ground faults in the downstream wiring or outlets, or an appliance plugged in that has a ground fault.

Comment: So the story goes I came home, opened the fridge and it was off.   Plugged the fridge into another outlet and the fridge works.   Tried reset the old outlet and nothing.   For this new one and yellow light which the instructions say means it is tripping

Answer (score 4):

I imagine you wouldn't care about the orange light if the appliance was working.

By far, the most common reason for this symptom: "the old GFCI tripped and refused to reset, and the new GFCI did the same thing" -- is that **the GFCIs were working properly. Their job is to detect something, and they detected it.**

Power *is supposed to* go from the hot terminal through the appliance to the neutral terminal, *and not anywhere else* i.e. and kill someone.  When it goes somewhere else, that is a Ground Fault and that is what Ground Fault Circuit Interruptors detect.

So.  What's actually happening is you have a ground fault in your wiring or an appliance.

How do you narrow it down?

First.  Unplug any appliance which you keep plugged into that GFCI.  Try resetting. Does it clear (stay on)? If so, plug things in one at a time until it trips again. Found your culprit.  Repair or replace.

Second. Every GFCI has a couple of terminals called LOAD. If anything is connected to those, those things are also protected by this GFCI, *which means, a fault there will trip it*.   Search the house for any outlets, switches/lamps, devices like radon pumps, you name it... which are also dead.

If anything can be unplugged, unplug it and see if the GFCI will reset now.  Try the dubious appliance on another GFCI.  (note that there are some wiring faults which will cause any appliance plugged in to trip the GFCI, but I'm assuming you haven't changed wiring lately *since you didn't mention it*).

Now we're down to hardwired loads and the wiring itself that comes off those Load terminals.  You know what is dead, so you have to make a best guess as to the wiring route, and pick junction boxes and disconnect both hot **and neutral**.  You must disconnect their neutral wire, despite everything you know about electricity. Neutral-ground faults are a thing and will trip a GFCI.

This is "divide and conquer" troubleshooting at this point.

Comment: Will have to problem solve I guess.  Not sure what is going on.

Comment: So basically find everything that is on the circuit and unplug it and go from there?   Only thing this outlet had on it was the fridge

Comment: @Scott it's not just what's plugged into it.  It's about what's on the *LOAD terminals* if anything. You cannot diagnose a GFCI problem without understanding how the downline protection works.

Comment: @Scott The GFCI outlets can be wired with other outlets downstream in a daisy-chain configuration, with the power running through the GFCI on the way to those downstream outlets. If that's how it's set up, any fault at the GFCI outlet, or downstream, will trigger it. If no wires are attached to the terminals labeled "Load"(Out), you do not have that daisy-chain setup. If there are wires connected to "Load" (as well as the usual wires connected to "Line"(In) you do have some kind of daisy-chain setup and need to investigate.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to attach the downstream wires to the LINE terminals (they take 2 wires; read the instructions for how) in which case the GFCI will protect only its 2 sockets.  For simplicity's sake, it would be better if most people did that.  Protecting a downline *without realizing you have done it* often leads to stupidity and waste.